# Is it possible to get files from Google Drive using reactjs?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, google-drive-api

I am trying to get data from Google Drive. is it possible to get data by react js Google Drive API call or for this we need a server side programming language like nodejs or Java etc. ?

If yes can you please provide some links for this?

Comment: Try to check at [this github post](https://github.com/RobinBobin/react-native-google-drive-api-wrapper#gdriveapiwFiles). It is a wrapper that facilitates the use of the google drive API. If I understand you right.

Comment: @MαπμQμαπkγVπ.0 this github url is good to refer. thanks

Comment: did it answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly speaking, no. But you can use node.js with Google Drive API

> https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/nodejs

Therefore I would advise having a little node.js backend server to interface with your react.js app.

Having said that, you may be able to hack your wat into using this API directly from react, but that's not how it's designed or intended to be used, and will have to face a ton of other issues.

Answer (score 0):

### **Setting up Google Drive API:**

- Create account in https://console.cloud.google.com/
- Create a new project or select an existing one.
- Enable the Google Drive API for your project.
- You can do this by clicking on "APIs & Services" > "Library" and then searching for and enabling the Google Drive API.
- After enabling the API, create credentials for your project. Choose "OAuth client ID" as the credential type and after that choose "API KEY".
- After you create both lets move ahead towards react app.

### **In react app**

- We will use **gapi-script** package for this install this using

  npm i gapi-script
- Import the package

  import { gapi } from "gapi-script";
- Use this snippet in your file.js

```js
const [data, setData] = useState([]);

const fileId = "Your File Id";
  useEffect(() => {
    function start() {
      gapi.client.init({
        apiKey: "Your-API-KEY",
        clientId:
          "Your-Oath-ClientID",
        scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",
      });

      gapi.client.load("drive", "v3").then(() => {
        try {
          gapi.client.drive.files
            .get({ fileId, alt: "media" })
            .then((response) => {
              const fileContent = response.result;
              setData(fileContent);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error);
        }
      });
    }

    gapi.load("client:auth2", start);
  }, []);
```

- You can get your google drive file id as shown

> https://drive.google.com/file/d/**your-file-id**/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score -4):

You can use axios module to make an api call from the component. Specifically in componenDidMount.

You can check out how you can use axios with react [here](https://alligator.io/react/axios-react/).

Comment: i am talking about google drive, not normal api call